# Sharepoint 2010: Laying out announcements in format like news sites?

Tags: sharepoint

I'm new to SharePoint 2010. I want to create easily maintainable newsitems (announcements / list) that are presented in the arrangements shown here:

http://www.dailymail.co.uk/ushome/index.html

Specifically the layout I'm after is identical to the news items in the center column:
- Headline above
- Thumbnail on left 
- Paragraph bottom right

Is this achievable? How? 
(Important that it's easy to maintain as a list).

Comment: This is a question for sharepoint.stackexchange really. The answer lies with using the publishing system, pages and content query web parts. Very achievable though.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint includes an Announcements list, that's certainly the easiest way with minimal maintenance. If you are not happy with the default look, the view settings will offer you more options (newsletter view, boxed view).

If this is not enough, then you'll need to edit the XSLT of the view (in SharePoint Designer for example).